# Regarding Adjective

Tags: adjectives

I want to know what is difference between below two sentence.

1) The given sentence is wrong

2 )The sentence is given wrong

Comment: "The given sentence" = "The particular sentence specified here." And "is given wrong" = "is rendered incorrectly." There is no logical reason that you couldn't have a sentence that said "The given sentence is given wrong" = "The particular sentence specified here is rendered incorrectly."

Comment: Should not have been closed. Interesting question that required only minor repair. It could use a more informative title, e.g. "Given - multiple meanings and grammar". Colin Fine gets the question and provides an excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

They have very different meanings.

"Given" has a specific, deictic, meaning - something like "the particular one being discussed" *only when used attributively*. This is the meaning in the first sentence: This particular sentence is wrong.

In the second sentence, "given" cannot have this meaning, and must say that the (unidentified) sentence has been given (by somebody), and given wrong - a rather unusual use of a subject complement. So it's unlikely to be said, but it sort of makes sense as "Somebody has given (eg copied or quoted) the sentence wrong".